# Using Stencils in XNA to Draw a texture in circles

Tags: c#, windows, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to make a small XNA-based game, and I need to be able  to draw a single texture inside multiple mobile circles around the screen, as if they were 'spotlights' revealing parts of a bigger picture.
While searching for how I would be able to do that, I found that stencils might be able to help me accomplish that, but I have no idea on how I'd use the stencils to do that.
If anyone has any information or ideas on how I can do that, I'd be very grateful.

Edit: I forgot to mention the game is in 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you need a mesh in the shape of the desired stencil, in this case a circle. XNA doesn't support many primitives, so you will need to approximate the circle with triangles.

Next, you render that mesh almost as normal but with:

```
graphics.DepthStencilState.DepthBufferFunction = CompareFunction.Never;
graphics.DepthStencilState.StencilEnable = true;
graphics.DepthStencilState.ReferenceStencil = 1;
graphics.DepthStencilState.StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace;
```

Now you have a stencil with the holes.

Then, you render the texture through the stencil, with normal settings but with:

```
graphics.DepthStencilState.StencilEnable = true;
graphics.DepthStencilState.ReferenceStencil = 1;
graphics.DepthStencilState.StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal;
```

For more information see the reference for the [DepthStencilState class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.depthstencilstate_members.aspx).

This is based on my knowledge of 3D. You may have to do more stuff if you want to use sprites.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm working with a 2D game.
Does any of that apply to 2D as well?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I'm not sure about rendering to the stencil buffer, though. That might require some 3D code.

Comment: I see... I'll keep looking into it and try to get it working with what I've got. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? If it does, please check it as the answer, so people know that the question is answered.